# SSRS generate one pdf per record automatically

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I've built a report which displays data from a db. This works fine, rendering the report correctly.

My query returns ~40,000 records. I would like to automatically generate a pdf file for each record, named using one of the fields returned by the query.

How do I automate this? I have Report Builder 3, and Visual Studio.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to create 40,000 pdf files?

Comment: Yes. I know it sounds odd, but this is what my boss has asked for. 40,000 pdfs, one for each record returned by my query.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a report that takes a parameter and generates the report for one record. Deploy to your Reporting Services server.

Then I'd write a quick program that loops through your data and passes each unique record value to the report as a parameter and saves it as a PDF with a unique name. It's quite easy to run reports programmatically and [Microsoft have some code to get you started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Chris, this does look like the best option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Enterprise SKU of SQL Server, look at [data driven subscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150.aspx). Another option could be creating report with one record per page, and then splitting resulting PDF into individual PDFs using some free tools.